# Azure Functions throws startup exception - A host error has occurred during startup operation

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-functions, .net-core-3.1

I have Azure Function developed on .NET Core 2.2, which was working fine, later I upgraded it to .NET Core 3.1 it was working all fine.

Recently I upgraded my Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 to Version **16.6.2**, since then all my Azure functions are failing to run on my local, with exception

> System.Private.CoreLib: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions, Version=3.1.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot
>   find the file specified. System.Private.CoreLib: Could not load the
>   specified file.

Startup up verbose

> Azure Functions Core Tools (2.7.2508 Commit hash:
>   4da36643c32783a832094318afcd679fa9d76455) Function Runtime Version:
>   2.0.13351.0 AZURE_FUNCTIONS_ENVIRONMENT: Development

I found similar issues faced by [others](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/1226#issuecomment-644659897,) but the comments over there seems like when Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions was in BETA stage, I am using Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions v3.0.7 (apparently stable version)

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Found the solution, edit project file, look for AzureFunctionsVersion tag, it was having v2, change it to v3 <AzureFunctionsVersion>v3</AzureFunctionsVersion> all working good.

Answer (score 2):

With .NET 6 and functions v4 also had the same problem, fixed by uninstalling both .NET 6 and Azure Function Core Tools and Reinstalling them Again.

Issue:
[image]

Resolved:
[image]